# Python Pandas - select rows between first row number and first occurrence from string

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for trying to help me :D

I have some data sorted by date and I entered the row number through the SQL PARTITION BY command, just like this output:

```
id  string_value  is_question  row_number
1   string-1          0             1
1   string-2          0             2
1   string-3          0             3
1   string-4          1             4
1   string-5          0             5
2   string-1          0             1
2   string-2          0             2
2   string-3          1             3
2   string-4          0             4
2   string-5          0             5
...
```

The column `is_question` represents that this string has values ​​that interest me

The question is: how do I select the rows between `row_number` ​​equal to 1 (always the first one) and `is_question` equal to 1 (the desired ending), the output to be:

```
id  string_value  row_number
1   string-1         1
1   string-2         2
1   string-3         3
1   string-4         4
2   string-1         1
2   string-2         2
2   string-3         3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is find the `row_number` for each `id` where `is_question` is `1`, then (using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and filtering) remove all rows for each `id` where the `row_number` is greater than that one. For example:

```py
questions = df[df['is_question'].eq(1)][['id', 'row_number']]
df1 = df.merge(questions, on='id', suffixes=['', '_y'])
df1[df1['row_number'] <= df1['row_number_y']].drop('row_number_y', axis=1)
```

Output

```
   id string_value  is_question  row_number
0   1     string-1            0           1
1   1     string-2            0           2
2   1     string-3            0           3
3   1     string-4            1           4
5   2     string-1            0           1
6   2     string-2            0           2
7   2     string-3            1           3
```

Comment: thanks, I just realized that I may have some duplicate values ​​from the is_question column and I want to keep only the first one, so I did a drop_duplicate (pandas) with id, string_value and is_question and keep='first', do you think that's the right approach?

Comment: another solution I thought about is creating a loop:
```for id in ids:
    df_id = df.loc[df['id']==id]
    df_aux = df_id.loc[: df_id[(df_id['is_question'] == 1)].index[0], :]
    df_final = df_final.append(df_aux)```

Comment: @mathdeoliveira using `drop_duplicates` the way you describe should work.